# Changing multiple elements with one drop down menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, getelementsbyclassname

Why doesn't this fiddle work:

[jsFiddle of changing span contents based on class name](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4GQx/1/)

```
<label>Change:</label>
<select name="list" id="list">
<option value="Test_a" selected>Test_a</option>
<option value="Test_b">Test_b</option>
<option value="Test_c">Test_c</option>
<option value="Test_d">Test_d</option>
</select>
<br/>1: <span name="result" class="result">Test_a</span>
<br/>2: <span name="result" class="result">Test_a</span>
<br/>3: <span name="result" class="result">Test_a</span>

<script>
var list1 = document.getElementById('list');
var tag1 = document.getElementsByClassName('result');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
list1.onchange = function () {
    tag1.innerHTML = this.value;
};
};
</script>
```

I want to be able to change all three `spans` (`class="result"`) to display the same value of drop down menu choice.

It works fine if I use `getElementById` and have only one `span` result with `id="result"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this is what you're after](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4GQx/2/). On change of the list, update all spans with the value of the list.

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('result');

list.onchange = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        spans[i].innerHTML = this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as I hoped it would.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't this fiddle work

Because `tag1` in your code is not a reference to a single DOM element, that would have an `.innerHTML` property, but the method returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection) of matching elements, that you have to loop through if you want to manipulate them individually:

```
list1.onchange = function () {
  for (var i=0, l=tag1.length; i<l; i++) {
    tag1[i].innerHTML = this.value;
  };
};
```